# MediaElement resume / reset on exit (Windows Phone)

Tags: windows-phone-8, reset, mediaelement, resume

I'm experimenting with a simple app that plays an audio file when run (isLooping=true, autoplay=true). It works fine but after closing it and opening it again, the audio file resumes playing the exact same second where I left it the time before, instead of starting over, as it should.

I tried doing audiofile.Stop() before audiofile.Play() but it doesn't work.

I'm guessing that the app never really "closes"? I'm not saving any progress in my app, it just launches and plays a file. That's all it does for now.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do not forget to call this before app exit:
    BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Stop();
and
    BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Close();

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to developing WP apps, where should I put those lines? I'm guessing inside some kind of onExit method, or something like that? Thanks again.

Comment: welcome man,you can put that in OnNavigatedFrom method of your screen also in App.xaml at Application_CLosing event.It will definitely reset your play.It this Helped you dont forget to accept answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Close() in OnNavigatedFrom of your screen and Application_Closing events.